# XAMPP Errors on Mac OS X Mojave

Tags: macos, xampp, macos-mojave, startup-error

I am running MacOS Mojave 10.14 with XAMPP 7.2.5

1. Earlier today, I tried to start up XAMPP after a crash/restart.  XAMPP Manager was unable to start the MYSQL Server.  Apache did start correctly.
2. Figuring there was a potential corruption, I used my Time Machine to restore my XAMPP folder (to a 36-hour old file) in Applications.
3. Now when I try to run XAMPP Manager, I get a "Cannot find any readable ctl script" error message.
4. I've tried to run MYSQL Server directly from CLI.  I receive the following message:

> ./mysql.server: line 200: my_print_defaults: command not found
>   Starting MariaDB
>    ERROR! Couldn't find MariaDB server (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysqld_safe)

Any thoughts on how to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has to do with a quirk with Time Machine - it does not completely regenerate all recorded folders/files.  A bit of a pain.

I was able to run XAMPP from the command line:

-> cd /Applications/xampp/xamppfiles
-> sudo ./xampp start

To check on MYSQL status:
-> mysql status -u [username] -p [password]

Issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

I spend a day on this and the solution in my case was:

- Uninstall XAMPP
- Delete all files except my databases folders from `⁨Applications/XAMPP⁩/xamppfiles/var⁩/mysql` (there was some .err and log files if I remember well)
- Reinstall XAMPP
- Reconfigure it. If you use different user than root to access your databases you need to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the "Cannot find any readable ctl script" error after a Time Machine restoration, too. I'm on 10.12.6 and XAMPP 5.6.

You are correct that it appears to be a TM issue, but I was able to resolve it by entering TM and specifically selecting the directories in XAMPP/xamppfiles/ that TM would not copy over by just selecting XAMPP/xamppfiles/. (In your case, you would **not** want to copy over /var/mysql, assuming you want to keep your data.)

Relief. There's nothing worse than realizing your trusty backup is not so trusty.

Comment: Yes, there's nothing worse than finding the backup is not a backup.  So imagine my surprise when, a week ago, I tried a total restore from my Time Machine.  No go.  Corrupted file.  What?  I spoke with Apple.  After two days of back and forth, they had no solution.  I tried a few hacks I found online.  No go.  I reinstalled Mojave, then was able to move the backup directory to my Mac.  All is well now, but this idea that TM is a one-click backup solution is now highly suspect.  It appears I am not the first victim, either.

Comment: It may sound ridiculous, but I suppose you could **also** back-up to a local network drive or to an external service. It would take a scheduled job that ran an rsync from your local to the remote at specific intervals. For my own case, I'll write a script that dumps certain dbs and saves them to a safe location nightly. Then I won't need TM.